# how do i add prefix contain str into a list in scrapy

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I changed the 'title_url' which is a list into a string and i am not getting output as i want,

```
import scrapy

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    base_url = 'https://www.yell.com'
    start_urls = ['https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?scrambleSeed=770796459&keywords=hospitals&location=united+kingdom']

def parse(self, response):
    all_data = response.css('div.row.businessCapsule--mainRow')
    for data in all_data:
        title_url = str(data.css('a.businessCapsule--title::attr(href)').extract())
        final_url = self.base_url + title_url
        items = {
 
            'Title Url' : final_url,
        }
        yield items
```

**ON output terminal shows like this**:

```
"https://www.yell.com/['/biz/western-care-ltd-yeovil-8342726/']", "https://www.yell.com/['/biz/livingstonecare-service-corby-9019909/'],.....]
```

**and  i want output like this**:

```
 ['https://www.yell.com/biz/western-care-ltd-yeovil-8342726/', 'https://www.yell.com/biz/livingstonecare-service-corby-9019909/'......]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `extract()` with `get()`

**Ex:**

```
def parse(self, response):
    all_data = response.css('div.row.businessCapsule--mainRow')
    for data in all_data:
        title_url = data.css('a.businessCapsule--title::attr(href)').get()
        final_url = self.base_url + title_url
        items = {
 
            'Title Url' : final_url,
        }
        yield items
```

[Note](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extract-and-extract-first): `.extract()` returns a list of items.